# detect auto-renewable subscription being renewed: what's the value of SKPaymentTransactionState?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am working on an app which has an auto-renewable subscription item implemented. No server is involved, at least not in the processing of subscriptions. I have seen a few posts stating that when this kind of subscription is "auto-renewed", the updatedTransactions method is called in the delegate and the SKPaymentState for that particular item is set to "Restored". However, In my case I receive it with the state "Purchased". Bit confusing. 
I am currently testing in the sandbox and I want to know what is the enum value when working on the live server. 
Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: I was also struggling to find the appropriate information and found the below links which can help:

https://pub.dev/documentation/iap/latest/iap/SKPaymentTransactionState-class.html https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/storekit.skpaymenttransactionstate?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12